# Import from relative path in Python: strange behavior

Tags: python, namespaces, python-import

As far as I understand from the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement), `from package import x` statement should bind only `x`, but not `package`, into the current namespace.
But in practice, if `package` is a *relative* name, it *is* also bound sometimes!

Let me provide an example. Consider the following file hierarchy:

```
root/
  package/
    __init__.py
    subpackage/
      __init__.py
```

**subpackage/__init__.py:**

```
foo = 42
```

**package/__init__.py:**

```
from os import name
from .subpackage import foo

print(globals().get('name'))
print(globals().get('os'))
print(globals().get('foo'))
print(globals().get('subpackage'))
```

Now let's run python (either v2 or v3) interpreter from the `root` directory and execute

```
>>> import package
```

The first three output lines are predictable:

```
posix
None
42
```

But the last one is `<module 'package.subpackage' ...>` rather than `None`, and this confuses me somewhat.

Have I missed something? Is it expected behavior? What is the reason?

---

The situation seems even more weird to me in this case:

```
root/
  __init__.py  # Empty.
  package/
    __init__.py
  another_package/
    __init__.py
```

**another_package/__init__.py:**

```
bar = 33
```

**package/__init__.py:**

```
from ..another_package import bar

print(globals().get('another_package'))
```

Now I run this *outside* the root:

```
>>> import root.package
None  # OK.
>>> dir(root.package)
['__builtins__', ..., '__path__', 'bar']  # OK.
>>> dir(root)
['__builtins__', ..., '__path__', 'another_package', 'package']  # What?!
```

Why did `another_package` appear in `dir(root)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to realize modules are loaded once at most (unless they are explicitly [reloaded](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload)). If a module is imported in multiple modules, the same module *object* is referenced by them all. E.g.:

**Module M.py**

```
bar = 10
```

**Module A.py**

```
import M
M.bar = 4
```

**Module B.py**

```
import M
M.bar = 6
```

So:

```
>>> import M
>>> M.bar
10
>>> import A
>>> M.bar  # A is referencing the same M module object!!
4
>>> import B
>>> M.bar # B is referencing the same M module object!!
6
```

Now, when the statement `from ..another_package import bar` is executed it is basically equivalent to executing `from root.another_package import bar`. Since `another_package` is indeed a module inside the `root` package, the statement succeeds which results with the following effects (there may be more, but for this purposes let's focus on these 3):

1. `root` is loaded *if not previously loaded* (its' `__init__.py` is run)
2. `bar` is imported into the current namespace
3. **`another_package` is added as an attribute to `root` module object**

Some developers are not completely aware of items 1 and 3.

Back to your question: Let's see what happens when `import root.package` is executed, in this order:

1. `root`'s `__init__.py` is run (because `root` wasn't loaded yet)
2. `package`'s `__init__.py` is run (because `package` wasn't loaded yet)
3. `from ..another_package import bar` is executed which has the side effects mentioned above, most notably, the (Yes. THE object. There is only one per each module, remember?) module object of `root` has the attribute `another_package` added to it.

This explains why `another_package` appears in `root`'s `dir`.

Comment: Thanks, now this makes perfect sense! I wasn't aware of the third effect indeed.
Finally found an [explanation in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules)